# Login en Android Studio con MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, phpmyadmin

llevo poco tiempo con Android Studio, tengo un login con una base de datos de MySQL con servicios PHP. El caso es que al validar recibo el siguente error:

com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 127.0.0.1 not permitted

Mi método para validar usuario es el siguiente:

```
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(!response.isEmpty()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivityLogged.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String>parametros=new HashMap<String,String>();
                parametros.put("usuario", editTextTextEmailAddress.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("contraseña", editTextTextPassword.getText().toString());
                return parametros;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

La URL es: http://127.0.0.1/iclementem/validar_usuario.php

Mi manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.trimbo_home_test1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Trimbo_Home_Test1"
        tools:targetApi="31">


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivityLogged"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Soy nuevo en el foro, no sé si esta es suficiente información, si hay que subir algo más decídmelo y lo subo. Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]!. Yo no puedo ayudarte, pero si sabes ingles puedes echar un ojo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/579895) donde da varias opciones para solucionar tu problema

Comment: Parece un problema en el servidor. ¿Qué pasa si accedes a `http://127.0.0.1/iclementem/validar_usuario.php` vía navegador e intentas pasarle los datos en la URL? Si tienes un certificado SSL instalado, es mejor usar `https` en la URL. Por cierto, evita usar la `ñ` y los acentos ... lo digo por la palabra `contraseña`, si no hilas fino con el charset vas a tener problemas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Tienes razón, error muy grave de mi parte utilizar ñ. Parece ser que el problema era simplemente que tenía que utilizar mi IP local en vez de localhost, también tuve que añadir la siguiente linea: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" Y con eso ya todo a empezado a funcionar correctamente. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @Pikoh Muchas gracias, me ha venido muy bien para solucionar mi problema. Un saludo :)

Comment: Es correcto lo que te señaló @Pikoh, después de un tiempo mis peticiones Volley empezaron a fallar, y era porque estaban bajo el protocolo `http` y no tenía `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` en el `Manifest`. En mi caso, dado que tenía un certificado SSL instalado, cambié las URL al protocolo `https` y problema resuelto.